IFS Character no effect after change
So I am running the following commands in interactive shell;
$ IFS=":"
$ for i in "foo:bar:apple"; do echo $i; done
foo:bar:apple

After changing the IFS my expectation was, it will split at : but it didn't. I thought it's not working because, the changed IFS is not passed to the new subshell, so I tried with export and still the same answer:
❯ export IFS=":"
❯ for i in "foo:bar:apple"; do echo $i; done
foo:bar:apple

How can I make it work for interactive shell? (I am on macos, using zsh)

Why is this question tagged with bash?

zsh doesn't do word-splitting (at least by default). Note that the for loop value wouldn't be split anyway, since 1) it's quoted, and 2) `$IFS is used to split variable/command/etc substitutions, not literal strings.

bash, ksh: IFS=:; a="foo:bar:apple"; for i in $a; do echo $i; done zsh: IFS=:; a="foo:bar:apple"; for i in ${=a}; do echo $i; done

Where do you expect word split to happen? "foo:bar:apple" is quoted, so no word split here. $i does not magically split either, because in zsh, word split happens before parameter expansion.
You can request word splitting with
echo ${(z)i}


It's not so much that word-splitting happens before parameter splitting, but that unquoted parameter expansions are not subject (by default) to field splitting as specified by POSIX.

@chepner: Are you sure? According to Posix Field Splitting: After parameter expansion ... the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting.

There is word-splitting, which is part of the parsing algorithm that recognizes parameters expansions, and field-splitting, which is performed on the result of a parameter expansion.

@chepner : I got it, and I now could find it in the POSIX definition as well. Could it be that bash (sloppily?) uses a different terminoloy? The bash manual, seems to use the term word splitting for what POSIX calls field splitting. POSIX's word splitting is token splitting in bash.

The bash man page is not always as precise as it could be. The POSIX specification has to be precise so that the behavior required for conformance is not open to interpretation.
